# Formatting the Month and Year from a datetime field in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to display only the month and year from a `Datetime` field in SQL Server 2008.

This should be formatted in the following way:

```
Jan 13
Feb 13
March 13
```

etc

I also need to group by and order by these results

I've tried many permutations of `Cast`, `Convert`, `DatePart` etc but can't quite get what I need.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you can upgrade to SQL Server **2012**, you would get `SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMM yy')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT (left(convert(char(11), date, 107), 3) + " " +
right(convert(char(11), date, 107), 2)) as date from 
(
    select date from yourtable 
    group by date 
    order by year(date) asc, month(date)asc
) as a
```

Convert `107` will give you the format `MMM dd, yyyy`, you only need month and last 2 digits of year so we'll use `left` function to get `MMM` and right function to get last 2 digits of year

**Update:** add support for sorting and grouping. And you can even add where clause into sub query to conditioning

Comment: No I need month and year. 13 being shorthand for 2013 :)

Comment: Answer edited, please try it and tell me whether it's useful for you or not :D

Comment: I'm trying to get the Group By and Order By functionality working with this now! I need to group my results by each month and have this in ascending order.

Comment: so just user `group by (left(convert(char(11), date, 107), 3) + " " +
right(convert(char(11), date, 107), 2))` and `order by Year(date) ASC, Month(Date) ASC`. I think it'll work, but you better test it first :D

Comment: I'm afraid that gives me the dreaded:
Column "datecolumn" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

That message has been the bane of my existence today!

Comment: Answer edited! The trick is, group and sort your table before convert it into your desired format. Hope this will help you :D

Comment: Forgot to say yesterday that this worked for me. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT MonthYear
FROM (  SELECT  CONVERT(CHAR(6),YourDate,112) MonthYearOrder, 
                CONVERT(CHAR(6),YourDate,107) MonthYear
        FROM YourTable
        GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(6),YourDate,112), 
                 CONVERT(CHAR(6),YourDate,107)) A
ORDER BY MonthYearOrder
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a utility function something like this

[Format SQL Server Dates (by Anubhavg)](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

Answer (score 0):

I would try this :

```
select convert(char(3), yourdatefield, 0) + " " + (YEAR( yourdatefield ) % 100) from yourtable
```